# XCTest: How to nest asynchronous calls (aka "How to not get an XCTest API violation")

Tags: xcode, swift, asynchronous, alamofire, xctest

I feel like I have a pretty common problem but somehow missed the memo on best practices.  I would like to figure out how to nest asynchronous calls within XCTest.

I am trying to test / cleanup some records in XCTest, via an Alamofire based REST API.  I am first doing a get, and then when the completion handler fires, I am trying to loop through the returned records, calling an asynchronous delete on each of them.

The first / obvious problem is that if I use XCTest expectations, I get the error that since I have to wait after the initial outer GET, and then try have to wait for subsequent delete calls, that I cannot create an expecation for the DELETE's since I am at that point waiting for the get completion:

```
func deleteAllFoos() {

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("deleteAllFoos")

    var foos:[Foo]!
    Api.foos({ i, f in
        foos?.append(f) },

        count: { c in
            foos = [Foo]()
            return c },

        success: { [unowned self] in

            for f in foos {

                let deleteExpectation = self.expectationWithDescription("\(f.id)")

                Api.fooDelete(f,
                    success: {
                        deleteExpectation.fulfill()
                    },
                    failure: { error in
                        XCTFail("deleteFoo failed")
                        deleteExpectation.fulfill()
                })
            }
            expectation.fulfill()
        },

        failure: { e in
            expectation.fulfill()
    })

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(300.0) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            XCTFail(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

It feels like I need a mixture of `NSRunLoop / runMode` as well, but outside of setup and teardown, this locks up on me.  I did peak through the underlying Alamofire code at one point, and I think recall it having a blocking issue in cases this like this (but this is just a unit test, so that isn't a meaningful concern).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I ended up finding an excellent reference here:

https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/xctest/

With the gist of it being, that you can create a base test class using GCD `dispatch_group_t` like this:

```
class XCTestAsyncTest: XCTestCase {

    static var dispatchGroup:dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()

    static func waitForGroup()
    {
        var didComplete = false;
        dispatch_group_notify(self.dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            didComplete = true
        })

        while !didComplete {
            NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode,
                beforeDate: (NSDate.distantFuture() as? NSDate)!)
        }
    }
}
```

So that you could write helper test functions like this (contrived) example:

```
static func addCourse(inout course:Course) {

    dispatch_group_enter(self.dispatchGroup)
    Api.courseAdd(course, success: { m in
        course = m
        dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroup) },
        failure: { error in
            dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroup)
            XCTFail("failed to create course")
    })
}
```

And call it like this:

```
static func initializeData() {

    var nora = Student()
    nora.first = "Nora"
    nora.last = "Norris"
    nora.gender = .Female
    createStudentAsync(&nora)

    var mary = Student()
    mary.first = "Mary"
    mary.last = "Morison"
    mary.gender = .Female
    createStudentAsync(&mary)

    waitForGroup()

    // populate Mary
    var mm1 = createCourseAsync(mary, text: "Mary's first class")
    addCourse(&mm1)
    var mm2 = createCourse(mary, text: "Mary's second class")
    addCourse(&mm1)
    var mm3 = createCourse(mary, text: "Mary's third class")
    addCourse(&mm1)

    waitForGroup()

    ...
```

This has been simple and effective in my testing.